# Auto Post to Facebook/Twitter

Tags: plugins

I've looked everywhere for this functionality and am very surprised that I can't find it...

Is there a plugin that allows auto posting of entry content to Facebook/Twitter/Other social media channel when the user hits Save?

If there isn't, then I'll build one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a plugin that posts to Buffer.com (which is free for up to very reasonable levels of activity).  Buffer in turn allows you to post to Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google+, etc.:

https://github.com/khalwat/buffer

I use it on several sites to do exactly what you describe.

Comment: You sexy beast, nice one! You've totally just saved me like a million hours of my life! I'll check it out now!

Comment: Do I need to write a plugin that has an `entries.onSaveEntry` function to call your plugin or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: Correct.  You just need to write a simple plugin that triggers the posting.  Here's an example:

Comment: I updated the README.md to include a simple example plugin that does what you want: https://github.com/khalwat/buffer

Comment: Legend! Nice one :)

Comment: Quick question, wondered if you'd come across this before... I used your updated code and modified it a little bit so that the push to buffer will only happen if the status is set to 'live': `if ($entry->section == 'News' && $entry->status == 'live')` However, if I write a post and set the status to disabled before I save, and then I go back into the entry, change the status to live and re-save, the push doesn't happen. Any ideas?